# Meaning of nice

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> It was good meeting your girlfriend. She seems nice.

If I think my friend's girlfriend is sweet and kind, would "nice" be the perfect and most natural adjective to use?

Comment: It seems to me a bit weak. Perhaps _really nice_ would do but a more specific word would be better. Many decades ago we were banned at school from ever using the word _nice_ except in the sense _exact_ as it lacks specificity.

Comment: The hackneyed *nice* doesn't mean anything nowadays. Be specific and expressive. Your "sweet and kind" would be much more genuine and descriptive than "nice".

Answer (score 3):

"Nice" is arguably the blandest of all positive adjectives. We use it all the time, and sometimes it is exactly the right thing to say. But there are times when someone can take offence because "nice" is not all they were hoping for. For example, when someone cooks you a meal, they might be hoping you say it is "delicious", and saying "it's nice" could show a lack of depth.

It is difficult to give advice on your specific example. You could say your friend's girlfriend is "nice". Saying "she's wonderful" might be too far in the context - your friend might think you are attracted to her. You could of course say she's "*really* nice".

Comment: I agree with Astralbee's response.  You could also say: "she seems like a nice person," which means "she seems like a kind, agreeable person."  It is stronger than saying: "she seems nice," which is often so vague as to suggest you have nothing really positive to say or don't want to bother giving an informative opinion.